# how to pass a java list to coldfusion cfselect?

Tags: java, list, select, coldfusion

somebody knows how to pass a list of object to a cfselect coldfusion tag? 
for example I have this java class

```
public class Person{
  private long id;
  private string name;

  //getters and setters
}
```

And I receive a java.util.List on coldfusion. How I get inside the `<cfselected>` the id and name attributes from the list?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<cfselect>` can only take a CF query and populate the options.

So... You'll have to build your own loop as such

```
<cfselect name="person">
  <cfloop array="#persons#" index="person">
    <option value="#person.getID()#">#htmlEditFormat(person.getName())#</option>
  </cfloop>
</cfselect>
```

If you don't need cfform, just use basic HTML's `<select>`